# Syntax error on token "}", delete this token

Tags: android, button, imagebutton

I am getting the above error at the end of this code:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);


    button= (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imgButton);
    button.setOnClickListener(imgButtonHandler);

    button1= (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imgButton1);
    button1.setOnClickListener(imgButtonHandler1);

    button2= (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imgButton2);
    button2.setOnClickListener(imgButtonHandler2);

    button3= (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imgButton3);
    button3.setOnClickListener(imgButtonHandler3);


    }
```

This is the code that follows it:

```
View.OnClickListener imgButtonHandler = new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            button.setImageResource(R.drawable.whiteon);
            button1.setImageResource(R.drawable.redoff);
            button2.setImageResource(R.drawable.yellowoff);
            button3.setImageResource(R.drawable.greenoff);

            TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewcategory);
            text.setText("WHITE (Hi-Po)");

        }
    };

    View.OnClickListener imgButtonHandler1 = new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            button1.setImageResource(R.drawable.redon);
            button.setImageResource(R.drawable.whiteoff);
            button2.setImageResource(R.drawable.yellowoff);
            button3.setImageResource(R.drawable.greenoff);

            TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewcategory);
            text.setText("RED (Significant)");

        }
    };

    View.OnClickListener imgButtonHandler2 = new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            button2.setImageResource(R.drawable.yellowon);
            button.setImageResource(R.drawable.whiteoff);
            button1.setImageResource(R.drawable.redoff);
            button3.setImageResource(R.drawable.greenoff);

            TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewcategory);
            text.setText("YELLOW (Serious)");

        }
    };
    View.OnClickListener imgButtonHandler3 = new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            button3.setImageResource(R.drawable.greenon);
            button.setImageResource(R.drawable.whiteoff);
            button1.setImageResource(R.drawable.redoff);
            button2.setImageResource(R.drawable.yellowoff);

            TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewcategory);
            text.setText("GREEN (Important)");


        }
    };
```

I've tried deleting the token as requested however when I do that it then says that all the "imgButtonHandler"s cannot be resolved to a variable.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Many Thanks

Comment: Have you cleaned the project?

Comment: The code you posted is all right from syntax point of view. There's likely some stray characters elsewhere that cause the syntax problem there.

Comment: Cleaned and still showing the same error. Thats what i'm thinking as the code works on its own as a separate app. So the error must be an extra "}" somewhere else in the code do you think?

Comment: can you post your whole code without import statements, it will help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private TextView text;
    private ImageButton button;
    private ImageButton button1;
    private ImageButton button2;
    private ImageButton button3;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewcategory);

        button= (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imgButton);
        button.setOnClickListener(imgButtonHandler);

        button1= (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imgButton1);
        button1.setOnClickListener(imgButtonHandler1);

        button2= (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imgButton2);
        button2.setOnClickListener(imgButtonHandler2);

        button3= (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imgButton3);
        button3.setOnClickListener(imgButtonHandler3);


    }

    View.OnClickListener imgButtonHandler = new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            button.setImageResource(R.drawable.whiteon);
            button1.setImageResource(R.drawable.redoff);
            button2.setImageResource(R.drawable.yellowoff);
            button3.setImageResource(R.drawable.greenoff);

            text.setText("WHITE (Hi-Po)");

        }
    };

    View.OnClickListener imgButtonHandler1 = new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            button1.setImageResource(R.drawable.redon);
            button.setImageResource(R.drawable.whiteoff);
            button2.setImageResource(R.drawable.yellowoff);
            button3.setImageResource(R.drawable.greenoff);

            text.setText("RED (Significant)");

        }
    };

    View.OnClickListener imgButtonHandler2 = new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            button2.setImageResource(R.drawable.yellowon);
            button.setImageResource(R.drawable.whiteoff);
            button1.setImageResource(R.drawable.redoff);
            button3.setImageResource(R.drawable.greenoff);

            text.setText("YELLOW (Serious)");

        }
    };
    View.OnClickListener imgButtonHandler3 = new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            button3.setImageResource(R.drawable.greenon);
            button.setImageResource(R.drawable.whiteoff);
            button1.setImageResource(R.drawable.redoff);
            button2.setImageResource(R.drawable.yellowoff);

            text.setText("GREEN (Important)");

        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Change the code that follows so it should look like:

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
case R.id.R.id.imgButton3:
button3.setImageResource(R.drawable.greenon);
            button.setImageResource(R.drawable.whiteoff);
            button1.setImageResource(R.drawable.redoff);
            button2.setImageResource(R.drawable.yellowoff);

            TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewcategory);
            text.setText("GREEN (Important)");
break;
case R.id.R.id.imgButton2:
 button2.setImageResource(R.drawable.yellowon);
            button.setImageResource(R.drawable.whiteoff);
            button1.setImageResource(R.drawable.redoff);
            button3.setImageResource(R.drawable.greenoff);

            TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewcategory);
            text.setText("YELLOW (Serious)");
break;
case R.id.R.id.imgButton1:
  button1.setImageResource(R.drawable.redon);
            button.setImageResource(R.drawable.whiteoff);
            button2.setImageResource(R.drawable.yellowoff);
            button3.setImageResource(R.drawable.greenoff);

            TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewcategory);
            text.setText("RED (Significant)");
break;
case R.id.R.id.imgButton:
 button.setImageResource(R.drawable.whiteon);
            button1.setImageResource(R.drawable.redoff);
            button2.setImageResource(R.drawable.yellowoff);
            button3.setImageResource(R.drawable.greenoff);

            TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewcategory);
            text.setText("WHITE (Hi-Po)");
break;

}
}
```

Comment: why is this an answer and not a comment?